# Retrieve value as character from NCR values coming from Database

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdbc, oracle11g, resultset

I'm facing issue to retrieve value as character from resultset. The result set is showing values in NCR format(eg; &#21488 ;&#21271 ;) instead of character (eg: 台北). I don't know how to get the characters from resultSet.

I'm getting value from resultSet

```
           while (resultSet.next()) {
                          resultSet.getString(1); // this value is coming as NCR / or some other text
                   }
```

I have tried one approach but I have issues with it

```
public static String ConvertDecimalNCRToString(String hex)
{
    String myString = hex.replace("&#", "");
    String[] split = myString.split(";");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) 
    {
        sb.append((char)Integer.parseInt(split[i]));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

if my String is " &#21488 ;&#21271 ;" then the program runs fine but the string can contain other values as well apart from NCR value like "stre1234&#21488 ;&#21271 ;" in this case the above approach fails. Could anyone can suggest some good approach to achieve it. I also wants to know if there are other ways through which I can get the character value directly from resultSet instead of NCR values?

Thanks in Advance ..!!

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't with how the data is stored in the database?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your data stored with numeric character references, you can translate those back to characters as part of your query using [the UTL_I18N.UNESCAPE_REFERENCE function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_i18n.htm#ARPLS71170):

```
select utl_i18n.unescape_reference('Test mixing &#21488;&#21271; with plain text')
from dual;

UTL_I18N.UNESCAPE_REFERENCE('TESTMIXING&#21488;&#21271;WITHPLAINTEXT')         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test mixing 台北 with plain text
```

Your client needs to be able to handle the Unicode characters, of course, and your session needs to be compatible too. For example, in a Linux PuTTY session with `export LANG="en_US.iso8859-1"` and `export NLS_LANG="ENGLISH_AMERICA.US7ASCII"`, that query run through SQL*Plus shows:

```
UTL_I18N.UNESCAPE_REFERENCE('TESTMIXING&#21488;&#21271;WITHPLAINTEXT')
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test mixing ?? with plain text
```

Changing `export NLS_LANG="ENGLISH_AMERICA.UTF8"` gets:

```
UTL_I18N.UNESCAPE_REFERENCE('TESTMIXING&#21488;&#21271;WITHPLAINTEXT')
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test mixing 台北 with plain text
```

If I run the same query through a Java program I get:

```
Test mixing ?? with plain text
```

With `export LANG="en_US.utf8"` (or, say, `ja_JP.utf8`) gets:

```
Test mixing 台北 with plain text
```

Other clients may need different settings, e.g. the operating system or Java locale. [You can read more in the globalisation guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/toc.htm).

You might also want to check whether the stored values really should be escaped in the first place.

Comment: I have tried it and it's giving me a different output like "¿¿"

Comment: What is your NLS_LANG or operating system locale set to? That looks like a display issue - your client isn't displaying the unicode characters properly.

Comment: operating system locale is English(United states)

Comment: Even a query directly in a database is giving me the abouve characters

Comment: select UTL_I18N.unescape_reference('&#21488;&#21271;') from dual give output as  ¿¿

Comment: Querying through what, SQL\*Plus? What is your NLS_LANG set to? What is your database character set? Which operating system - might affect what it can display in a US locale.